# Mirth 3.0 clustering

Tags: mirth

I have to implement the Mirth 3.0 clustering. Do any of you have implemented clustering in Mirth or any idea/reference how this can be achieved. How this can be achieved with and with Mirth appliances.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

Clustering with the Mirth Appliance(s) is very straight forward.

Comment: Can you please explain what are the steps I need to follow for Mirth 3.0 clustering?

Comment: Please share me the reference URLs from where I can read about Mirth clustering through Mirth Appliances or different means, if possible

Comment: Guys,
Please feel free to write about how clustering can be achieved in Mirth without using Mirth Appliances.

Comment: This is not an answer. Responses like these should probably be comments.